# Alpha-Beta to dq0 Transformation in STM32

Tags: stm32

I am working on a STM32 project and I want perform Alpha-Beta to dq0 transformation (in Simulink: [alpha-beta-to-dq0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foxPv.png)). The concept is that I have a single phase inverter that is connected to grid and the grid voltage passes through PLL and I have two identical signals, alpha and beta (beta same as grid and alpha same as grid but shifted by 90 degrees).

I tried the following function for park transform:

```
#define Fs 1000.0f  // Sampling frequency in Hz
#define w0 (2.0f * M_PI * 50.0f)  // Angular velocity of the fundamental frequency in rad/s

// Transformation matrix coefficients
float32_t park_cos = 0.0f;
float32_t park_sin = 0.0f;

float32_t alpha = 0.0f;
float32_t beta = 0.0f;
float32_t theta = 0.0f;
float32_t d = 0.0f;
float32_t q = 0.0f;

// Park transformation function
void park_transform(float32_t alpha, float32_t beta, float32_t theta, float32_t *d, float32_t *q) {
    // Calculate the transformation matrix coefficients
    park_cos = arm_cos_f32(theta);
    park_sin = arm_sin_f32(theta);

    // Perform the transformation
    *d = alpha * park_sin - beta * park_cos;
    *q = alpha * park_cos + beta * park_sin;
}
```

where theta is w0 * t (because the integral of w0 is theta=w0 * t).
To implement t in STM32 I use TIM3 so t gets +1 (sec.) every second (as a real time clock):

```
volatile uint32_t timer_counter = 0;
volatile float t = 0.0f;

void TIM3_IRQHandler(void) {
    if (TIM3->SR & TIM_SR_UIF) {
        TIM3->SR &= ~TIM_SR_UIF;
        timer_counter++;
        t = (float)timer_counter / 20000.0f; // assuming sampling frequency of 20kHz
    }
}

void init_timer(void) {
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM3EN; // enable timer 3 clock

    TIM3->PSC = 0; // no prescaler
    TIM3->ARR = 4500; // period of 4500, gives 20kHz frequency

    TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS; // only overflow generates interrupt
    TIM3->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UIE; // enable update interrupt

    NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM3_IRQn); // enable timer 3 interrupt in NVIC

    TIM3->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN; // enable timer
}
```

I know that there is also TIMx -> CNT register in order to avoid the above implementation but it is not working. Do you know how can I implement Park Transformation in STM32?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if "I use TIM3 which is 1Hz" is correct. Per the comments in `init_timer()`, isn't it rolling over at 20kHz? Having an ISR run 20,000 times per second is probably asking a lot.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yes, I made a mistake. TIM3 isn't 1Hz. It is implemented in order to give "t" +1 every second. I edited it. Furthermore, init_timer() is called once to initialize TIM3.